# Query never finishes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have a query for a report that never finishes. I've allowed it to run for upwards of 20+ mins without completing. Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @start DATE, @end DATE

SET @start = '7-1-2019'
SET @end = '8-20-2019'

SELECT cg.*
    ,ba.std_StandardAcctNo AS bonus_acct
FROM [CustSalesTrend_Growth] cg
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT std_standardacctno
    FROM [CustSalesTrend_Growth]
    WHERE eleph_Period_Date BETWEEN @Start
            AND @End
        OR ideal_Period_Date BETWEEN @Start
            AND @End
    ) ba ON ba.std_StandardAcctNo = cg.std_StandardAcctNo
    AND cg.Period_Date >= @Start
    AND cg.Period_Date <= @End
WHERE [Appearance_Count] <> 0
    AND Period_gp <> 0
ORDER BY cg.std_StandardAcctNo
```

One of my first steps in diagnosing this is doing a simple select * on the view being referenced (`CustSalesTrend_Growth`) and it will finish running in about 30 seconds on average, pulling 12k records. Given this, I'm a little perplexed as to how the preceding query could add so much complexity to the execution, to the point that it never finishes. In my mind, the query above is relatively simple, so any ideas as to why this is happening?

EDIT: query for the view CustSalesTrend_Growth

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CustSalesTrend_Growth]
AS
WITH basedata
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.order_num
        ,a.Period_Date
        ,a.year AS std_the_year
        ,a.Month AS std_the_month
        ,a.customer_alias AS std_StandardAcctNo
        ,b.SalesPerson_name
        ,isnull(ac.counter, 0) [Appearance_Count]
        ,isnull(b.[Year], 0) [The_Year]
        ,isnull(b.[Month], 0) [The_Month]
        ,isnull(b.Customer_Alias, 0) [CustomerName]
        ,sum(isnull(b.Gallons, 0)) [Gallon_Qty]
        ,sum(isnull(b.[Total Sale], 0)) [Total_Sale]
        ,sum(isnull(b.[Gross Profit], 0)) [Total_Gross_Profit]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.year
            ,a.month
            ,b.Customer_Alias
            ,convert(INTEGER, convert(VARCHAR(4), a.Year) + right('00' + convert(VARCHAR(2), a.month), 2)) AS order_num
            ,convert(DATE, convert(VARCHAR(2), a.Month) + '/01/' + convert(VARCHAR(4), a.Year)) AS Period_Date
        FROM Complete_Sales_V2 a
        JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Alias
            FROM Complete_Sales_V2
            ) b ON 1 = 1
        ) a
    JOIN PDI_Warehouse_2049_01.dbo.Appearance_Count ac ON a.Customer_Alias = ac.customer_alias
    LEFT JOIN Complete_Sales_V2 b ON a.Customer_Alias = b.Customer_Alias
        AND a.Month = b.Month
        AND a.Year = b.Year
    GROUP BY a.order_num
        ,a.Period_Date
        ,a.year
        ,a.Month
        ,a.Customer_Alias
        ,b.SalesPerson_Name
        ,ac.counter
        ,b.[Year]
        ,b.[Month]
        ,b.Customer_Alias
    )
    ,saleslist
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT SalesPerson_Name
        ,Appearance_Count
        ,Period_Date
        ,std_the_month
        ,std_the_year
        ,std_StandardAcctNo
        ,isnull(sum(Total_Gross_Profit), 0) Period_GP
    FROM basedata
    GROUP BY SalesPerson_Name
        ,Appearance_Count
        ,Period_Date
        ,std_StandardAcctNo
        ,std_the_month
        ,std_the_year
    )
    ,core_GP
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Customer_Alias
        ,convert(DATE, convert(VARCHAR(2), a.month) + '/01/' + convert(VARCHAR(4), a.year)) AS Period_Date
        ,sum(a.[Gross Profit]) AS Period_GP
    FROM Complete_Sales_V2 a
    JOIN PDI_Warehouse_2049_01.dbo.appearance_count ac ON ac.customer_alias = a.Customer_Alias
    GROUP BY counter
        ,convert(DATE, convert(VARCHAR(2), a.month) + '/01/' + convert(VARCHAR(4), a.year))
        ,a.Customer_Alias
    )
    ,GroupedData
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT cgp.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,cgp.Period_Date
        ,sum(cgp.[Total_Gross_Profit]) AS Period_GP
        ,Appearance_Count
    FROM basedata cgp
    GROUP BY cgp.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,cgp.Period_Date
        ,Appearance_Count
    )
    ,GP_Grouping
AS (
    SELECT std_StandardAcctNo
        ,min(Period_Date) AS range_start
        ,max(Period_Date) AS range_end
        ,count(*) AS range_count
        ,GP_group
    FROM (
        SELECT std_StandardAcctNo
            ,Period_Date
            ,CASE 
                WHEN Period_GP = 0
                    THEN 0
                ELSE 1
                END AS GP_Group
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY std_StandardAcctNo
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN Period_GP = 0
                        THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                    END ORDER BY Period_Date
                ) AS rn
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY std_StandardAcctNo
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN Period_GP = 0
                        THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                    END ORDER BY Period_Date
                ) - row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY std_StandardAcctNo ORDER BY Period_Date
                ) AS grp
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY std_StandardAcctNo ORDER BY Period_Date
                ) AS grp2
        FROM GroupedData
        ) a
    GROUP BY std_StandardAcctNo
        ,grp
        ,GP_Group 
    )
    ,GP_Group2
AS (
    SELECT gd.*
        ,max(gpg_prev.range_end) AS last_zero_group -- , gpg.range_count  
    FROM GroupedData gd
    LEFT JOIN GP_Grouping gpg ON gd.std_StandardAcctNo = gpg.std_StandardAcctNo
        AND gd.Period_Date BETWEEN gpg.range_start
            AND gpg.range_end
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM GP_Grouping
        WHERE GP_Group = 0
            AND range_count >= 12
        ) gpg_prev ON gpg_prev.std_StandardAcctNo = gd.std_StandardAcctNo
        AND gpg.range_start > gpg_prev.range_end
    GROUP BY gd.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,Period_Date
        ,Period_GP
        ,Appearance_Count
        ,gpg.range_count 
    )
    ,GP_Group3
AS (
    SELECT gd.*
        ,Appearance_Cnt_Rel = CASE 
            WHEN gd.last_zero_group IS NULL
                THEN Appearance_Count
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY gd.std_StandardAcctNo
                    ,gd.last_zero_group ORDER BY gd.Period_Date
                    )
            END
    FROM GP_Group2 gd
    )
    ,almost_done
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT bd.order_num
        ,bd.Period_Date
        ,bd.std_the_year
        ,bd.std_the_month
        ,bd.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,CASE 
            WHEN bd.[Appearance_Count] > 0
                THEN bd.[Appearance_Count]
            WHEN isnull(c.Appearance_Count, 0) > 0
                THEN c.Appearance_Count + 1
            WHEN isnull(d.Appearance_Count, 0) > 0
                THEN d.Appearance_Count + 2
            WHEN isnull(e.Appearance_Count, 0) > 0
                THEN e.Appearance_Count + 3
            ELSE 0
            END AS Appearance_Count
        ,bd.[The_Year]
        ,bd.[The_Month]
        ,bd.[CustomerName]
        ,bd.[Gallon_Qty]
        ,bd.[Total_Sale]
        ,isnull(c.Appearance_Count, 0) AS Prev_Count
        ,isnull(d.Appearance_Count, 0) AS month2_Count
        ,isnull(e.Appearance_Count, 0) AS month3_Count
        ,CASE 
            WHEN bd.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN bd.SalesPerson_Name
            WHEN c.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN c.SalesPerson_Name
            WHEN d.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN d.SalesPerson_Name
            WHEN e.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN e.SalesPerson_Name
            ELSE 'NA'
            END [SalesPerson] 
        ,CASE 
            WHEN bd.[Appearance_Count] IS NULL
                AND c.[Appearance_Count] IS NULL
                AND d.[Appearance_Count] IS NULL
                THEN e.Period_GP
            ELSE 0
            END [Lost_Gross_Profit]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN bd.Appearance_Count = 1
                THEN bd.Total_Gross_Profit
            ELSE 0
            END AS 'New_Cust_GP'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN bd.Appearance_Count <= 12
                THEN bd.Total_Gross_Profit
            ELSE 0
            END AS 'Young_Cust_GP'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN bd.Appearance_Count > 12
                THEN bd.Total_Gross_Profit
            ELSE 0
            END AS 'Old_Cust_GP'
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY bd.std_StandardAcctNo
            ,bd.std_The_Year
            ,bd.std_The_Month ORDER BY (bd.std_StandardAcctNo) DESC
            ) AS UNI_Period
        ,bd.Total_Gross_Profit AS SalesP_GP
        ,isnull(cg.Period_gp, 0) AS Period_gp
        ,CASE 
            WHEN isnull(b_prev.Period_gp, 0) > 0
                THEN isnull(b_prev.Period_gp, 0)
            WHEN isnull(d.Period_gp, 0) > 0
                THEN isnull(d.Period_gp, 0)
            WHEN isnull(e.Period_gp, 0) > 0
                THEN isnull(e.Period_gp, 0)
            ELSE 0
            END AS Prev_Period_GP
        ,h.Mat_MoM_Shift
        ,CASE 
            WHEN isnull(b_prev.Period_gp, 0) > 0
                THEN isnull(b_prev.Period_gp, 0)
            WHEN isnull(d.Period_gp, 0) > 0
                THEN isnull(d.Period_gp, 0)
            WHEN isnull(e.Period_gp, 0) > 0
                THEN isnull(e.Period_gp, 0)
            ELSE 0
            END * h.Mat_MoM_Shift AS Expected_GP
        ,isnull(c.Period_gp, 0) AS True_Prev_GP
        ,isnull(d.Period_gp, 0) AS True_2month_GP
        ,isnull(e.Period_gp, 0) AS True_3month_GP
        ,ideal_candidate = CASE 
            WHEN ((isnull(c.Period_gp, 0) + isnull(d.Period_gp, 0) + isnull(bd.Total_Gross_Profit, 0)) / 3 >= 800)
                AND isnull(c.Period_gp, 0) >= 150
                AND isnull(d.Period_gp, 0) >= 150
                AND isnull(bd.Total_Gross_Profit, 0) >= 150
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
            END
        ,eleph_candidate = CASE 
            WHEN ((isnull(c.Period_gp, 0) + isnull(d.Period_gp, 0) + isnull(bd.Total_Gross_Profit, 0)) / 3 >= 5000)
                AND isnull(c.Period_gp, 0) >= 1000
                AND isnull(d.Period_gp, 0) >= 1000
                AND isnull(bd.Total_Gross_Profit, 0) >= 1000
                THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N
'
            END
    FROM basedata bd
    LEFT JOIN core_GP b_prev ON bd.std_StandardAcctNo = b_prev.Customer_Alias
        AND b_prev.Period_Date = dateadd(month, - 1, bd.Period_Date)
    LEFT JOIN saleslist c ON c.std_StandardAcctNo = bd.std_StandardAcctNo
        AND c.Period_Date = dateadd(month, - 1, bd.Period_Date)
        AND CASE 
            WHEN bd.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN bd.SalesPerson_Name
            ELSE c.SalesPerson_Name
            END = c.SalesPerson_Name
    LEFT JOIN saleslist d ON d.std_StandardAcctNo = bd.std_StandardAcctNo
        AND d.Period_Date = dateadd(month, - 2, bd.Period_Date)
        AND CASE 
            WHEN bd.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN bd.SalesPerson_Name
            WHEN c.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN c.SalesPerson_Name
            ELSE d.SalesPerson_Name
            END = d.SalesPerson_Name
    LEFT JOIN saleslist e ON e.std_StandardAcctNo = bd.std_StandardAcctNo
        AND e.Period_Date = dateadd(month, - 3, bd.Period_Date)
        AND CASE 
            WHEN bd.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN bd.SalesPerson_Name
            WHEN c.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN c.SalesPerson_Name
            WHEN d.SalesPerson_Name IS NOT NULL
                THEN d.SalesPerson_Name
            ELSE e.SalesPerson_Name
            END = e.SalesPerson_Name
    LEFT JOIN RicoCustom.dbo.[Rico_Global_Monthly] h ON h.month = bd.std_the_month
    LEFT JOIN core_GP cg ON bd.std_StandardAcctNo = cg.Customer_Alias
        AND cg.Period_Date = bd.Period_Date
    )
    ,get_ideal
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT min(ad.Period_Date) AS ideal_Period_Date
        ,ad.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,rc.last_zero_group
    FROM almost_done ad
    LEFT JOIN GP_Group3 rc ON rc.Period_Date = ad.Period_Date
        AND rc.std_StandardAcctNo = ad.std_StandardAcctNo
        AND rc.Period_GP = ad.Period_gp
    WHERE ideal_candidate = 'Y'
        AND (
            rc.Appearance_Cnt_Rel BETWEEN 3
                AND 6
            ) 
    GROUP BY ad.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,rc.last_zero_group
    )
    ,get_elephant
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT min(ad.Period_Date) AS eleph_Period_Date
        ,ad.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,rc.last_zero_group
    FROM almost_done ad
    LEFT JOIN GP_Group3 rc ON rc.Period_Date = ad.Period_Date
        AND rc.std_StandardAcctNo = ad.std_StandardAcctNo
        AND rc.Period_GP = ad.Period_gp
    WHERE eleph_candidate = 'Y'
        AND (
            rc.Appearance_Cnt_Rel BETWEEN 3
                AND 36
            ) 
    GROUP BY ad.std_StandardAcctNo
        ,rc.last_zero_group
    )
SELECT rc.Appearance_Cnt_Rel
    ,gi.ideal_Period_Date
    ,ge.eleph_Period_Date
    ,ad.*
FROM almost_done ad
LEFT JOIN GP_Group3 rc ON rc.Period_Date = ad.Period_Date
    AND rc.std_StandardAcctNo = ad.std_StandardAcctNo
    AND rc.Period_GP = ad.Period_gp
LEFT JOIN get_ideal gi ON ad.std_StandardAcctNo = gi.std_StandardAcctNo
    AND ad.Period_Date = gi.ideal_Period_Date
LEFT JOIN get_elephant ge ON ad.std_StandardAcctNo = ge.std_StandardAcctNo
    AND ad.Period_Date = ge.eleph_Period_Date
WHERE order_num > 201001
```

The indexing I have exists on the source table, Complete_Sales_V2. It is as follows:

index desc:
`clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY`

index keys:
`Customer_Alias, SalesPerson_Name, year, month, Invoice_Number`

Comment: To really help you here, we need the full DDL of your tables involved (including indexes) and the query plan (use Paste the Plan and put the link in your question), Othrwise we can only guess. Do you really need `cg.*`, and if so, *do* you have a covering index on your table `CustSalesTrend_Growth`? *Also, as a side note, if you are going to use date and time datatypes, use an unambiguous format (`yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssssss`). Certainly don't use values without leading 0's.*

Comment: And 20 minutes is not 'never'. I've seen queries that required hours to run (they weren't optimized, or indexing was bad), but they still run to completion and produce results. Did you look at the query plan? Are there any indexes? How many rows are in the source table?

Comment: I had the understanding that the only way to get the query plan is after it finishes running. Am I wrong? Source table has 89k rows. Select * on it takes 1 second, and it has a clustered index. By seeing the "full DDL", is that to mean the results of an Alt + F1 of the table/view(s) involved?

Comment: *"I had the understanding that the only way to get the query plan is after it finishes running. Am I wrong?"* Yes, both SSMS and ADS can obtain the Estimated Query Plan (Ctrl+L in SSMS).

Comment: Where is the Paste the Plan you mentioned?

Comment: @Dale Burrell I googled it. I came across a site that appears to be what was being referenced. I was assuming Paste the Plan was a part of either StackOverflow or SSMS, a part I had never heard of before. Sorry if I've frustrated you, just trying to learn here...

Comment: And I've hit a wall. The maximum is 2mb on that site, and even SSMS is telling me that the XML is too large to open with XML editor, having a max file size of 10 mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you can query the view I suggest selecting your view into a temp table prior to performing the query. This will simplify the query plan, allowing you to inspect it. And may hopefully speed it up.

I note in your original query you are filtering you main table against @Start and @End in the join condition. I don't think you want to do that. I think it should be in the where clause.

Also you can probably pre-filter the temp table so long as you can work out which records may be required (I couldn't because you compare to 3 different dates).

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '7-1-2019', @end DATE = '8-20-2019';

-- Best practice is to list the actual columns required
-- You may also be able to pre-filter here based on @start and @end
-- But as you compare them to 3 different columns in the query I don't know enough about your logic to know if this is possible or not
-- You can also add indexes to the temp table if they would speed things up
select *
into #cg
from [CustSalesTrend_Growth];

SELECT cg.*
    , ba.std_StandardAcctNo AS bonus_acct
FROM #cg cg
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT std_standardacctno
    FROM #cg
    WHERE eleph_Period_Date BETWEEN @Start AND @End
    OR ideal_Period_Date BETWEEN @Start AND @End
) ba ON ba.std_StandardAcctNo = cg.std_StandardAcctNo
WHERE [Appearance_Count] <> 0
AND Period_gp <> 0
AND cg.Period_Date >= @Start
AND cg.Period_Date <= @End
ORDER BY cg.std_StandardAcctNo;

drop table #cg;
```

Comment: This is great. I did not realize that putting things into a temp table would have such a drastic effect. Your query here executed in 48 seconds, which I think will work fine. I don't suppose you could recommend an article/blog that goes into more detail as it pertains to query tuning/performance, perhaps even with comparisons between scenarios where you would use a CTE/temp table/etc. over another? Thank you for this. I really would love to better understand why this works better.

Comment: @jw11432 Just read about each object type separately and you be will able to connect the dots.

Comment: @jw11432 the reason this works is because it forces SQL Server to execute 2 separate execution plans. Whereas when you use a view or a CTE it actually combines all the SQL into a single execution plan. In this case the single execution plan was too complex for SQL Server to be able to generate an efficient execution plan, whereas when forcing it into two plans it was able to make each of them efficient.

Comment: @jw11432 performance tuning of queries is a **very large** topic there is not one resource that covers it. Look at "Brent Ozar"'s webside, maybe try "stairway to SQL", there are many books written on it.

Comment: Understandable it is large and complex, I would have assumed nothing less. :) Thank you for that explanation, that helps a lot and it will now be engrained in my brain as a trick to use in other similar scenarios. I will check that site out, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query that uses CTEs. I do not have the schema so some of my assumptions may not be correct. Please verify the query before you execute.

```
WITH t1 AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM CustSalesTrend_Growth 
  WHERE Appearance_Count <> 0
  AND Period_gp <> 0
  AND Period_Date between @Start and @End
),
t2 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT std_StandardAcctNo
  FROM CustSalesTrend_Growth
  WHERE eleph_Period_Date BETWEEN @Start AND @End
  OR ideal_Period_Date BETWEEN @Start AND @End
)
select t1.*, t2.std_StandardAcctNo AS bonus_acct
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.std_StandardAcctNo = t1.std_StandardAcctNo
ORDER BY t2.std_StandardAcctNo
```

Comment: It appears the syntax here is correct for what I need, but I've been running this query for about 5 mins now and it still hasn't pulled results, but I do very much appreciate your time.

Comment: @jw11432 Let me know what indexes you have on the table CustSalesTrend_Growth.

Comment: CustSalesTrend_Growth is actually a view, but it has no index. I just googled and discovered you can apparently index a view; I thought only a table could be indexed. However, I've posted the query behind this view in my question above as an edit.

Comment: @jw11432 You will be well served by appropriately indexing the view and your original SQL query should work fine.

Comment: That is sound advice, thank you for that confirmation.